# ListView: динамическое изменение высоты скрула

Tags: android, listview

Есть ListView с адаптером, в адаптере LinearLayout (в принципе это неважно, пробовал и другие), TextView, ImageView. Так вот, когда LinearLayout содержит большой ImageView, при скруллинге к этому месту высота скрулбара уменьшается, а как только мы его пролистываем, скрулбар снова ресайзится в исходное положение как и был до скруллинга в этом место. И так с каждой позицией в ListView, которая содержит какой-то большой объект. Идеи?

Comment: скриншот бы

Comment: Непонятно - где вопрос? Что надо сделать то?

Comment: @Barmaley ну ListView же вроде как лениво заполняется соответственно местоположение скролла меняется, человеку наверно хочется постоянное местоположение скролла в зависимости от видимого элемента листвью